# 'The specified operation is not valid' message when trying to use CountDistinct in a local report

Tags: reporting-services, localreport

I need to hide the row with totals if group contains only one row.

I use expression for row visibility `=iif(CountDistinct(Fields!ChannelId.Value)>1,False,True)`, but get the message 'The specified operation is not valid'.

I also tried to explicitly pass the name of DataSet or GroupName. It din't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `ChannelId` a calculated field in the dataset? I would suggest showing the report XML definition too if possible.

Comment: @JonathonOgden No, it's just the column of the row. And this column is also used for groupping

Comment: It could be erring out on NULL datasets

Answer (score 0):

You need a second parameter specifying the dataset name from your grouping:

`=CountDistinct(Fields!ChannelId.Value, "YourDSName") > 1`

Comment: This changes nothing. Neither the name of the dataset, nor the name of the group.

Comment: @voroninp - You need to assign it some value to make the expression return true / false.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Row visibility can only be true or false, which is Boolean.   It can't be 3 or 12 like a RowCount can be.

You need to make an expression that evaluates to a Boolean value and cast it as a Boolean.   Psuedocode would be "If the RowCount is less than some value, then false, else true".

Comment: yes, it is the part of expression. I use iif for visibility

Comment: That's not the expression you posted in your question.  Please edit your question with your exact code.

Comment: Changed. But the original expression does not work either. I simply try to to show the value of the expression for debug purpose.

Comment: @voroninp - You don't need all that, its simply this `=CountDistinct(Fields!ChannelId.Value, "YourDSName") > 1` I have this working on several of my reports.

Answer (score 0):

Holy WTF!

Report does'not allow to count by field which is used for grouping.

After I changed it to `=CountDistinct(Fields!ChannelName.Value`)` it showed me the value.